# Replacing a specific character in filename when that character is repeated

Tags: python, operating-system

So I have a list of filenames like so:

```
gry_235545_y1.day
gry_234456_y1.day
gry_233356_y1.day
gry_232256_y2.day
```

And I want to change the `y` in `y1` to `a`.  So far I have:

```
for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for n in f:
        if n.endswith(('sub', 'db')):
            pass
        else:
            if n[2][0] == 'y':
                print(n.replace('y', 'a'))
```

But this changes **all** the `y` characters in the filename to `a` when I only want to change the `y` right before the extension.  My question is how can I change the character in the filename in a specific location?

Comment: Use `find` to get you the second `y`; use that index to replace the character as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the 'y' to '_y' so that it is specifically replaces _y#.

```
for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for n in f:
        if n.endswith(('sub', 'db')):
           pass
        else:
           if n[2][0] == '_y':
              print(n.replace('_y', 'a'))
```

Comment: This is the hacky way of doing it. This could work fine if you will always have `_y` to work with. and there will never be another `_y` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions.

```
import re
s = 'gry_235545_y1.day'
re.sub(r'_y(\d+)',r'_a\1',s)
> 'gry_235545_a1.day'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach even though it seems longer than other answers. I think its clear to understand, whats happening.

```
  filenames = ["gry_235545_y1.day", "gry_235555_y1.day", "gry_235522_y1.day" ]
  for file in filenames:
  first_word = file.split('_')[0]
  second_word = file.split('_')[1]
  y1_word = "a1"
  extenstion = file.split('.')[-1]
  new_file_name = "".join(first_word+"_"+second_word+"_"+y1_word+"."+extenstion)
  print(new_file_name)
```